# full screen on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code

```
function errorHandler() {
   alert('mozfullscreenerror');
}
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mozfullscreenerror', errorHandler, false);

// toggle full screen
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}

// keydown event handler
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 70) { // F or Enter key
    toggleFullScreen();
  }
}, false);
```

when I click on button then it is full screen the whole `body`

but I want to show only a div `testfullscreen` in full screen

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Add a fiddle of your code

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/8nC4x/38/)

Comment: @Durga it is showing but scrollbar is not showing in the full screen

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE(11).

Following the pointers by Zuul on this thread, I edited his code to include IE11 and the option to full screen any element of choice on your page.

JS:

```
function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
    // ## The below if statement seems to work better ## if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (document.msfullscreenElement && document.msfullscreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
            elem.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.body)">
```

Where "document.body" is any element you so wish.

Also note that trying to run these full screen commands from the console do not appear to work on Chrome or IE. I did have success with Firebug in Firefox though.

One other thing to note is that these "full screen" commands don't have a vertical scrollbar, you need to specify this within the CSS:

```
*:fullscreen
*:-ms-fullscreen,
*:-webkit-full-screen,
*:-moz-full-screen {
   overflow: auto !important;
}
```

The "!important" seems to be necessary for IE to render it